# Is there any way to know the cause I cannot install app from Google Play

Tags: google-play-store, sony-xperia-s, sony-xperia-x10-mini

I'm using Sony Xperia S (also I have old SE Xperia X10 Mini) and want to install [mytaxi app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=taxi.android.client&hl=en). But Google Play says that I'm not eligible to do this and I do not understand why! I've found an apk in the internets and it works fine, but I want to know the reason and have updates.

Comment: Doesn't it give any reason along ­­– such as "not compatible with any of your devices" or "not available in your country"? What is the exact wording?

Comment: @Izzy it says "This app is incompatible with all of your devices."

Comment: Contact the developer and let them fix it.

Comment: This problem is rather frequent and only the developers can fix it. Reason is probably that the app wants features like GPS, certain screen sizes or a minimum Android version. One of those requirements is not met although it runs just fine. Tje devs need to relax that declaration...

Comment: Thank you guys for the comments! I've send them a mail. Also my phone have GPS module. Never saw Androids without it. @ce4 you can make it an answer - I'll be glad to accept.

Comment: @ce4 - Probable reason is forgetting to include `android:required="false"` in a [<uses-feature> declaration](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html).  It defaults to true if not included, making the feature mandatory rather than optional.

Comment: Sorry, I'm only using my mobile atm, hence the qick comments. Answer comes in a minute. See also: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/53460/incompatible-devices-with-my-newly-released-app-why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is rather frequent and only the developers can fix it.

Reason is probably that the app wants features like GPS, certain screen sizes or a minimum Android version. One of those requirements is not met although it runs just fine.

So the obvious way to get this fixed is to contact the developers and have them relax that declaration..